# Producer-Consumer wtih remote message queue as producer and ExecutorService as local consumer

Tags: java, executorservice, producer-consumer, future

I've got a producer-consumer situation where I have a *remote* message queue that needs to be periodically polled for new task messages and a local `ExecutorService` which executes the tasks. There are many of these task executors polling the MQ. The local executor will have a fixed number of threads with a relatively fixed throughput.

The problem though is that I don't want the primary message loop to just keep consuming remote messages if it can't process them, but I want it to be constantly working if there is more work to do. I want to have at least one task ready for each thread, but not too much more as to not starve other workers.

Classic Producer-Consumer. The problem is that the `ExecutorService` abstracts away some of the information that I need to know (total threads, number of busy threads, etc.). The actual number of threads is configured at startup when it creates the corresponding `ExecutorService`. This is then injected into my main worker loop along with the abstraction for the remote message queue.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Currently, I'm leaning towards a decorator pattern around the `ExecutorService` to track the counts. I'm curious is there a more elegant solution that any out there has used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) implementation of the `ExecutorService` then you'll have access to the information you need that's missing from the `ExecutorService` (e.g. `getActiveCount()` and `getTaskCount()`)

Comment: See! I knew I was missing something obvious. Thanks. :) I was concerned if my inc/dec counts started to drift off by one then I'd have a mess on my hands.